# PyTorch does not converge when approximating square function with linear model

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to learn some PyTorch and am referencing this discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/minimal-working-example-of-optim-sgd/11623)

The author provides a minimum working piece of code that illustrates how you can use PyTorch to solve for an unknown linear function that has been polluted with random noise.

This code runs fine for me.

However, when I change the function such that I want t = X^2, the parameter does not seem to converge.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable

# Let's make some data for a linear regression.
A = 3.1415926
b = 2.7189351
error = 0.1
N = 100 # number of data points

# Data
X = Variable(torch.randn(N, 1))

# (noisy) Target values that we want to learn.
t = X * X + Variable(torch.randn(N, 1) * error)

# Creating a model, making the optimizer, defining loss
model = nn.Linear(1, 1)
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# Run training
niter = 50
for _ in range(0, niter):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    predictions = model(X)
    loss = loss_fn(predictions, t)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print("-" * 50)
    print("error = {}".format(loss.data[0]))
    print("learned A = {}".format(list(model.parameters())[0].data[0, 0]))
    print("learned b = {}".format(list(model.parameters())[1].data[0]))
```

When I execute this code, the new A and b parameters are seemingly random thus it does not converge. I think this should converge because you can approximate any function with a slope and offset function. My theory is that I'm using PyTorch incorrectly.

Can any identify a problem with my `t = X * X + Variable(torch.randn(N, 1) * error)` line of code?

Comment: Hey you are trying to get X**2 from X without multiple layers(1 i/p,1 o/p) and your lr is also slightly higher. (Increase the iters maybe)

Comment: "I think this should converge because you can approximate any function with a slope and offset function" - What parameter do you think your algo should converge to? Without having thought about the problem too much, I don't see a reason this should converge...

Comment: @AndyM I left out a crucial detail that explains my troubles I believe. I'm essentially only trying to approximate a "segment" of X^2. In this scenario, it should converge. However, I'm clearly not limiting my input data to this range.